# Dotnet: How to turn off/ on in Mac?

Tags: .net, macos

probably a dumb question.. but I cannot found how to "turn off" .net core on my Mac.

I'm using it only for development of a website w/ visual studio code. When I stop development for the day I want to turn off .net (but not uninstall it). After I close everything down .net is still using 2+gb ram.

I cannot find any command to turn it on or off in the docs.

Any ideas are welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: .Net Core is just a library, it's not a background service or anything. If you see something running under "dotnet", that's a real application running there. Use `kill` to kill it if you can't figure out the application you started.

Comment: I think dotnet is just not stopping threads when I close the app. I wondered if there was an easy way to stop all instead of going into activity monitor and killing one by one.

Comment: That still sounds like a broken app to me, fix it to handle its own threads and shutdown. Specifically for threads, there's a `IsBackground` property that doesn't take the thread into account when considering whether it's time to shut down your application yet or not.